# How to clone a react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am implementing the Picture-in-Picture function of my media player component.

My code is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-esdfhm?file=buttons%2FMuteButton.js).

I want to forward the mute state of the original player to the mini-player.

Unfortunately, there are some problems that occurred in the Chrome browser,

I found that if I popup the mini-player first, and then toggle the mute state in the original player,

the mini-player mute state can follow the original player.

If I unmute the original player first, and then popup the mini-player, the mini-player mute state **cannot** follow the original player.

However, in the Firefox browser, the mini-player mute state can match with the original mute state all the time.

I have tried to change the render method of the MediaPlayer class as follow:

```
render(){
    var media;
    if (this.state.showMiniPlayer){
        media=this.normalPlayer.media;
    } else {
        media=null;
    }   
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <NormalPlayer
                muted={this.state.muted} 
                ref={instance => { this.normalPlayer = instance; }}
                showFullScreen={this.state.showFullScreen}  
                showMiniPlayer={this.state.showMiniPlayer}
                toggFullScreen={this.toggFullScreen} 
                toggleMute={this.toggleMute}
                togglePInP={this.togglePInP}>
            </NormalPlayer>
            {media}
        </Fragment>    
    )
}
```

However, I got the following message:

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child
```

So, how can I fix the problem?

The following screenshot is for Pavan Kalyan:
[image]

Comment: {media} is the reason for the error check the value of media, it should not be an object

Comment: Thank you for your inspiration Pavan Kalyan , I fix the problem.
I update the code to stackblitz.